# How do I know which is the correct AI to connect to a system's "Synch Out" pin?

Tags: signal, wire-terminals, daq

I am trying to measure a square signal that I should be obtaining from the "Trigger In" (Trigger Input)  and the "Ground" pins being connected to the oscilloscope.

The signal we ought to be getting is not the one shown, so I was advised to connect the "Synch Out" pin (Frame Synchronisation Output) to the [DAQ*](https://www.ni.com/en-gb/support/model.usb-6351.html) AI (Analog Input).

**How do I know which is the correct AI "socket" to connect the "Synch Out" to?**

**Is it as simple as just connecting a cable to this "socket"?**

*I leave this [link](https://www.ni.com/getting-started/set-up-hardware/data-acquisition/analog-voltage) which might help better understand the system.*

---

*Data Acquisition System that, once the correct signal is obtained, must be connected to the 3 pins above mentioned.

*I have only ever studied theoretical physics before so this is a completely new field for me, if my explanation was not good enough, I can try to further explain it.*

Comment: *The signal we ought to be getting is not the one shown* - I don't see any images of the signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to the computer software. A DAQ is just a way to get signals into a computer. It doesn't care what the signals are. If you are looking at a signal as a graph on your screen for example, and you look at AI 2, but your signal is hooked up to AI 1, you won't see it - for obvious reasons. If you moved the signal to AI 2 *or* switched the graph to display AI 1, you'd see it.

So it depends on what the computer is doing. This can't be answered based on only the electronics side.